# How to tokenize a string in mysql database

Tags: mysql, string, split, phpmyadmin, tokenize

Is there any possibility to tokenize a string in a mysql database (phpmyadmin)?

I need a function that splits a string like this

```
ID123|this sentence contains 5 tokens
```

into

```
ID123|1|this
ID123|2|sentence
ID123|3|contains
ID123|4|5
ID123|5|tokens
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: This would be considerably easier to do in PHP itself. Why do you need to do it in the database? If your tokenization is non-trivial, like breaking on punctuation or parenthesis, you're going to end up with a monster of a SQL statement in a hurry.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to program using php. I already have this database and do know some basic mysql syntax. Punctuation, symbols ecc. doesn't matter..The function should simply split tokens after every space. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**The literal answer:**

You would have to create a stored procedure to split strings, and then apply it multiple times in order to tokenize your string:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
x VARCHAR(255),
delim VARCHAR(12),
pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
delim, '');
```

Use this as such: `SELECT SPLIT_STR(string, delimiter, position)`

However, it should be noted that this is going to require a great deal of manually generated looping and checking in order to fully implement, as MySQL does not have any real string manipulation functions built in to speak of, so you would have to entirely roll your own to do it this way, and in the process make your data layer significantly harder to maintain, and your debugging efforts nightmarish. Therefore this is a very bad solution to your problem, however this is the literal answer to what you asked.

**The better answer:**

Use your scripting language to perform string editing tasks before insertion into the database. Generally string manipulation and logic should not take place in the data layer.

In PHP:

```
$prefix = 'ID123|';
$string = 'ID123|this sentence contains 5 tokens';
$res = explode(' ', ltrim($prefix, NULL, $string));
foreach (&$res as $token) {
    $token = $prefix . $token;
}
```

In Javascript (if you are using Node.js or something):

```
var prefix = "ID123|";
var str = "this sentence contains 5 tokens";
var res = str.split(prefix).pop().split(" ");
for (i=0;i<res.length;i++) {
    res[i] = prefix+res[i];
}
```